# Stuck in multi line mode when executing firebase functions shell

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I falsely hit insert key on keyboard which made firebase functions shell act weird whenever I hit return "enter" it does not execute the command,it just opens new line instead.

I'm using firebase functions shell emulator to test my cloud functions before deploying to firebase.

firebase > var d = require(./logFunData);onFirstSearch(d);
...
...
...

My cloud function "onFirstSearch" is fine and worked well but only after I hit Insert key the shell emulator started to not execute the command.

[image: Stuck in multi line command]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out ,seems like I was missing adding quotes to data file name
as

```
var data = require('./logFunData.json');
```